# Compute product of all combinations of a list

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have a list of 11 numbers, and I want to test the product of all combinations against some rule (2^11 possibilities).

I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python), but it seems to return a list of all combinations, which I think would take up to much memory.

My C++ thinking would be to go through each binary number `0x001` to `0x7FF` and multiply each number where its corresponding bit is 1.

Example with 4 numbers: My list is `[2, 3, 5, 7]`

The first binary number would be `0001` giving - 2 = 2

Later we would get to `1110` and the product would be `3 * 5 * 7 = 105`

Is there a better way of doing this in `python`? A bit manipulation doesn't seem like the right way to go.

Comment: @Bazingaa thanks for the edit. Had some weird formatting bug going on, posted on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373704/what-is-going-on-here-there-is-no-code

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There are 11! combinations of the list ordering, but order doesn't matter for multiplication so it would reduce to 2^11.

Comment: `itertools.permutations` returns an **iterable** (**not** a list), so you don't have to worry about memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that should work with long lists without memory problems (with a "functional" approach) that uses iterables is:

```
import itertools
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

my_list = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21]

# define helper partial function useful to return an iterable of combinations with r elements
combinations_with_r = partial(lambda r: itertools.combinations(my_list, r = r))

# generate all combinations, print them with their products
for r in map(combinations_with_r, range(1, len(my_list) + 1)):
    for j in r:
        print(j, np.prod(j))
```

You can declare `my_list = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21], dtype = 'int64')` to mitigate overflow problems.

Comment: If I count the permutations in where you print `j, np.prod(j)` it comes out at 2046 which seems to low. Some results of np.prod are also giving negative numbers. Is numpy using signed ints underneath?

Comment: Hi! They should be 2^11 = 2048. I haven't seen negative products in my output, can you give an example of a combination of an example `my_list` behaving that way?

Comment: Sorry, the count is correct.
Some examples below of negatives
(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23, 29, 31) 1965880678

(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 19, 23, 29, 31) -1087225998
(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31) -1752139174
(2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31) 1052902646
(2, 3, 5, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31) -1413272482
(2, 3, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31) 1457392362
(2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31) -1865980026
(3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31) 1495997257

Comment: For some reason my version on numpy seems to be working with signed 32 bit ints.
(2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31) -1865980026
Should be 66,853,496,710
Subtracting 2^31 32 times leave us with -1865980026

Comment: Doesn't overflow on my environment, but maybe declaring `my_list = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21], dtype = 'float64')` might give a bit extra leeway on yours (?).

Comment: That worked thanks, although I used int64 in the end not float. Edited the answer to reflect this